# SQL Update based on and Select Result From Same Table

Tags: sql, select, nested, dbisam

I am going to do my best to clearly describe what I am trying to do.

I am using a DBISAM SQL database.

We sell t-shirts, and lots of different kinds. I am trying to update our product database with values from other products in the database. here is an sample:

Products Table

```
SKU           Product      LongDesc
01-S          01           Great Looking T-Shirt
01-M          01           
01-L          01
02-S          01           
02-M          01           Amazing Ladies T
02-L          01
03-32         03           Long t
03-34         03
03-36         03
```

I would like to write an update script that will update the **LongDesc** field on all **SKU**'s that don't have a **LongDesc** but I would like that to get there **LongDesc** from other **SKU**'s with the same **Product**

IN THE END I WOULD LIKE THE TABLE TO LOOK LIKE THIS:

```
SKU           Product      LongDesc
01-S          01           Great Looking T-Shirt
01-M          01           Great Looking T-Shirt
01-L          01           Great Looking T-Shirt
02-S          01           Amazing Ladies T          
02-M          01           Amazing Ladies T
02-L          01           Amazing Ladies T
03-32         03           Long t
03-34         03           Long t
03-36         03           Long t
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE p
SET p.longdesc = pp.longdesc
FROM products p
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT a.sku, MAX(a.longdesc) AS longdesc
    FROM
    (
        SELECT LEFT(sku FOR (POS('-', sku) - 1)) AS sku, longdesc
        FROM products
    ) a
    GROUP BY a.sku
) pp ON LEFT(p.sku FOR (POS('-', p.sku) - 1)) = pp.sku
```

Comment: Hey Zane, the Products are not always 2 digit numbers, they can range from 4 to 8 chars long.

Comment: @GaryFoster, just as long as it is before the `-` ?

Comment: it's also not always before the dash. Some samples of Products would be 0001-112, 0001-114, 0002-2, 0555-98, 0555-96